# why does tkinter window lag and don't display what is told to

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a program that scrapes a website for Islamic prayer times and then sounds an alarm when one of them is due. I have been successful so far for the coding part, but when it comes to GUI with Tkinter it has been a cumbersome task. My problem is when I am trying to show the times **scraped** in a simple window. It first lags and sometimes even never shows up and when it does it never shows the text and keeps showing the loading circle. What is the problem here?

```
#import libraries

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime , timedelta
from os import popen
from time import sleep
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from tkinter import *

#html parsing
manar = "http://almanar.com.lb/legacy/salat.php" #webpage
page = urlopen(manar)           
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")

date_box = soup.find("h2")#("div" ,attrs = {"class":"time full-date"})#attribute needed



#getting times(part1)
today = date_box.text.strip()
#today = today.split("  ")
today = " ".join(today.split())
print(today)

#current time
now = datetime.now()
print("at: " + str(now))

#notifications
toaster = ToastNotifier()



#getting times(part2)
day_parts = ["prayer-time emsak","prayer-time fajer","prayer-time shorook","prayer-time dohor","prayer-time aser","prayer-time moghreb","prayer-time ishaa","prayer-time midnight", ]
prayer = []
for part in day_parts :
    day_part =  soup.find("div",attrs = {"class":part})
    day_part = day_part.text.strip()
    day_part = " ".join(day_part.split())
    prayer.append(day_part)



prayer_times = []
for pray_time in prayer:
    if prayer.index(pray_time) == 1:
        pray_time = pray_time.split()[1:3]
        prayer_time = ": ".join(pray_time)
        
        
    elif prayer.index(pray_time) == len(prayer) - 1:
        pray_time = pray_time.split()
        word = " ".join(pray_time[:2])
        prayer_time = word + ": " + pray_time[2]
        
        
    else:    
        prayer_time = ": ".join(pray_time.split())
        
    print(prayer_time)
    prayer_times.append(prayer_time)
    
    toaster.show_toast("Prayer Time:", prayer_time)


text_prayers =  "{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(prayer_times[0],prayer_times[1],prayer_times[2],prayer_times[3],prayer_times[4])


#Sounding Adhan


seconds_hms = [3600, 60, 1]
now_seconds = sum([a*b for a,b in zip(seconds_hms, [now.hour, now.minute, now.second])])
times = []
for pnt in prayer_times:
    lpnt = pnt.split()
    if len(lpnt) == 3:     #because midnight is 2 words
        time = lpnt[2]
    else:
        time = lpnt[1]
    times.append(time)    

times_in_sec = []
for dpt in times:   #dayparttime
    
    
    adhan_time = [int(n) for n in dpt.split(":")]
    
    dpts = sum([a*b for a,b in zip(seconds_hms,adhan_time)])
    
    times_in_sec.append(dpts)

#msg box
root = Tk()
root.title("prayer times")
frm = Frame(root,bg="yellow")#,height= 20, width=30,)
txt = Text(frm,height= 10, width=20)

txt.insert(INSERT,text_prayers)
txt.pack()

ok = Button(root,text="ok", fg="green",command= root.destroy)
ok.pack(side="bottom")

frm.pack()

root.mainloop()


#main process
if __name__ == "__main__":



    while True :
        for tis in times_in_sec :
            time_diff_seconds = tis - now_seconds
            
            
            if time_diff_seconds < 0:
                continue
            
            elif time_diff_seconds == 0 :
                print("praying time!")
                popen("c://users//Dell//downloads//adhan.mp3")
                toaster.show_toast("next adhan starts in : ","%s" %timedelta(seconds=time_diff_seconds))
                
            elif time_diff_seconds > 0 :
                print("next adhan starts in : %s" %timedelta(seconds=time_diff_seconds))
                toaster.show_toast("next adhan starts in : ","%s" %timedelta(seconds=time_diff_seconds))
                sleep(time_diff_seconds)
                popen("c://users//Dell//downloads//adhan.mp3")
                
else:
    print("this is a module")
```

Comment: It could be this line `sleep(time_diff_seconds)` or the fact that your `while` loop gets executed only after you end the program

Comment: This line is executed after the Tkinter code, so I don't see why it has anything to do with Tkinter's process. Yet I did try this solution and I still got the same output.

Comment: That could be the reason, your `while` loop is interfering with tkinter `mainloop()` and hence the app freezes, using `sleep()` is also the reason for the lag, like said by @EricRoy as the answer, use `after()`

Answer (score 0):

When you put `root.mainloop()` in your code, this will control the window until you close it. Then it will continue with the next lines. So, whatever you insert after it won't be runned while the window is open.

You can change the `root.mainloop()` with these 3 equivalent lines. You can include them in your `while True`, and you can put them more than once (if you feel it's still laggy):

```py
while True:
    root.update()
    root.update_idletasks()
```

Another thing that you should change is the usage of `time.sleep()`. During this function the window will lag, as it won't be updated with the lines above. You could try using `tk.after()`:

> tkinter.after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)
> Requests Tkinter to call function callback with arguments args after a delay of at least delay_ms milliseconds. There is no upper limit to how long it will actually take, but your callback won't be called sooner than you request, and it will be called only once. [[archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html)]

So, in conclusion, the important thing in tkinter is to always run the `mainloop()`, or equivalent. This way your window will never lag.

Comment: I am new to coding and this just a practice code I tried to create. Yet I do know this, the problem is that even when I try to close the Tkinter window it doesn't close, the cursor just keeps showing loading sign(circle spinning), so I always close it from the task manager. Even when the Tkinter window shows up it doesn't show the frame and the widgets. It just keeps loading forever. I tried these two solutions but none of them worked. I even tried commenting out the whole if _name_ == "_main_" part but the problem still existed.

Comment: You need to insert in your while True the 2 lines that I said above, and then you should change the delay for the after(). Note that the after will callback **a function**, as the program will continue running. So you need to create a function that does what you want it to do after the delay.